# Angular.js: Only include one nested view (ui-view) in loop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to Angular.js and trying to implement a nested controller into a list. I.e. imagine a list of messages, and once a user clicks on one of them, it expands and exposes a list of comments/meta-info for this message. I want this to be in its own nested controller.

I believe my controller etc. is all set up correctly, the only problem is that when I click on a message, it reveals the comment box under every message, not just the one clicked.

Here is the HTML of my main view:

```
<ul ng-show="messages.length">
  <li ng-repeat="message_i in messages">
    <a ui-sref=".message({id: message_i.id })">
      {{message_i.title}}
    </a>
    <div ui-view></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Everything works perfectly, i.e. when clicking on the `ui-sref` link, the nested view appears, it's just rendered in every single `ui-view`, not just the one of the clicked message.

I tried adding a condition to the `ui-view`-div to make sure it's the right iteration of the loop, e.g. `ng-if="message_i.id==id"`, but this is giving me an error. I guess I can't simply access the nested `.message`'s `id` parameter.

So is there a way to solve this with an if-condition? Or do I have do it another way?

**~ EDIT ~**

For completeness, here is a Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yh1vawj7/10/

Comment: share the code where you are handling the `click` event and displaying comments. A jsFiddle would be better

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to web frontend, but figured there would be an easy solution to this. I'll have a look at jsFiddle and edit.

Comment: Oh and btw, I don't have any code to handle the click event. It is all done by angular with the `ui-sref` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some more research I found out

1. What I'm trying to do is basically the behavior of [Angular UI Bootstrap's Accordion](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)
2. It is easier / better (?) to not use a nested view in this case.

So I updated my code to use accordion and added an event so that my comments/meta-data is loaded on click the header. It's a shame I couldn't keep the custom URL for each opened object, though. If anyone has a better idea of implementing this, or to solve exactly my original problem, please post an answer.